# PHP Redis does not seem to store data in-memory

Tags: php, redis

I'm learning how to implement Redis to help reduce load on my MySQL database.
Currently I have tried implementing it on queries that are either heavy or often called, This caused my pages to load slower.

I've tested this on localhost and a hosted Redis Server (redis.io cloud)

I started to look into the issue further trying to understand why it was slower.
One of the reasons seems to be that each time i use $redis->get(), it fetches results directly from the redis server, instead of in-memory cache.

I did this as a test:

```
$redis = new \Redis();
$redis->connect($_ENV['REDIS_HOST'], $_ENV['REDIS_PORT']);
if (isset($_ENV['REDIS_PASSWORD'])) {
    $redis->auth($_ENV['REDIS_PASSWORD']);
}
$redis->setOption(\Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, \Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP);

$redis->set('test', 'test');
echo $redis->get('test');
echo $redis->get('test');
```

Following code results in this log (fetched by RedisInsight):

```
13:28:50.583 [0 127.0.0.1:54623] "SET" "1rel:site5:test" "s:4:"test";"
13:28:50.583 [0 127.0.0.1:54623] "GET" "1rel:site5:test"
13:28:50.583 [0 127.0.0.1:54623] "GET" "1rel:site5:test"
```

I might be misunderstanding this, but shouldn't Redis save the result of `$redis->get('test')` to memory, in order to fetch it faster and without delay?

Should I instead create a helper class to handle this myself, storing results in cache?

Comment: You must have misunderstood. You'd better always connect to a local redis server. You can create [replicas](https://redis.com/glossary/distributed-caching/) for distributed caching.

Comment: "but shouldn't Redis save the result of ... to memory" - it does. Redis _is_ an in-memory store. Specifically, the Redis _server_ is an in-memory store. When you use `$redis = new \Redis()`, you are instantiating the Redis _client_ which doesn't do any caching. Its only job is to talk to the Redis _server_.

Comment: If you benchmarked a local Redis server and a traditional RDBMS like MySQL, you'd usually fine that Redis is faster. However, if you throw serialization into the mix, things might change. If you are comparing MySQL with straight arrays against Redis with serialization, it is absolutely possible that the Redis path might appear to be slower, but it is probably because of the deserialization. You might also find that this path uses more memory and it has to swap to disk, depending on how you deserialize things.

Comment: @shingo so a solution like Redis Cloud is not a good option? https://redis.io/

Comment: @ChrisHaas okay thanks, thats explains something. I maybe thought that the file "dump.rdp" (that was automaticly created in my root dir) acted as a temporary cache or something between client and server.

Thanks for feedback on serialization - this could properly be my bottle neck regarding performance.

Comment: Are you talking about an RDB file? If so, to the best of my knowledge that is a binary file format for Redis, something that could be backed up if you do such a thing. A lot of people use Redis purely for caching, and if Redis reboots, all cached data is lost. My understanding is that RDB files can be used to survive this, and that's commonly used if priming your cache is very expensive.

Comment: @ChrisHaas sorry yes, RDB file. Okay thanks for your input and help here. I have misunderstood the way redis worked, and learned a few things also.

Comment: Tried to do some research on my localhost (local redis server) checking performance of the redis server under different circumstances vs. database.

Currently nothing beats the database: https://imgur.com/a/fGPa7dw

Comment: I think you have misunderstood again, Redis Cloud is not a redis server.